# Seemingly random high memory usage notification .NET application

Tags: .net, memory

I really am at a loss here. One of the applications I developed for the company I work at triggers a high memory usage warning every now and then. The interval seems to be like once a week and the application is running full time in the background.
The task manager has a column called "Memory - Peak working set" which is never more than ~60MB, and the regular memory usage of the application is around 45MB. And the "physical memory" usage in the task memory never seems to be even near 100%, more in the range of 50-60%. Also I have never noticed or received reports of the application causing any problems when you just press cancel and let it run.
This is a screenshot of the message: (application name blurred out)

[image]

My question is: what more can I do to find the cause of this warning? The application is developed in .NET 4.5.2, but I was not able to find any weird things with the debugger attached and different profilers running.

Edit: the application that is suggested to be closed to free up memory is always the same. (The custom developed .NET application)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This diagnostic is not necessarily triggered by your program.  Ask IT staff to look at the machine, they need to pay attention to the paging file and the kernel memory pool.  Questions about that belong at superuser.com

Comment: try to run program into your local machine for a while and use `Environment` namespace fields to define CPU/RAM usage - say every second and log that at the file for example or local DB if possible . Root cause might be pretty much anything ... Also if target machine is ancient - say 1GB RAM then that might be a problem/

Comment: This is unfortunately not on just one machine... However the Windows installation is always based on a standard image, so that might be causing it. The PC's have 4GB's of RAM.... The actual memory usage really is not the problem.